# How to restrict access to a static page in Ghost blogging platform?

Tags: blogs, ghost-blog

I need to create a static page with ghost (ghost.org) but restrict access either by gmail userid OR some users I create. Is this possible in ghost or would this require some hacking in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to put Ghost behind Nginx (or Apache), and setup [Basic HTTP Auth](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10) for URL of your restricted post.

No need to hack anything in Ghost or node. But keep in mind that Basic HTTP Auth is not secure enough (it is good for simple restriction but not against some kind of bad guys)